# eofexception during the execution of the server FTP

Tags: java

When I try to send or receive a file, I keep getting this error is written below. I tried to find the reason with debugging and each time it stops on this line:

```
ObjectInputStream Inputs = new ObjectInputStream (socket.getInputStream ());
```

These are the errors that appear running after I entered the path of the keyboard file:

```
java.io.EOFException
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully (ObjectInputStream.java:2353)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort (ObjectInputStream.java:2822)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader (ObjectInputStream.java:804)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream. <init> (ObjectInputStream.java:301)
  at ClientFTP.riceviFile (ClientFTP.java:101)
  at ClientFTP.main (ClientFTP.java:44)
```

**class ServerFTP**

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ServerFTP {

    private final int PORTA=2000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerFTP server = new ServerFTP();
        try {
            server.listen();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    // Metodo per l'ascolto sulla porta predisposta

    private void listen() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORTA);
        System.out.println("Server FTP in ascolto ....");

        // ciclo infinito per accettare connessioni
        do {
            Socket connessione = server.accept(); // accetto connessioni in ingresso
            GestoreFTP gestore = new GestoreFTP(connessione);
            gestore.run();
            // inserisco un ritardo per il main
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){}
        } while (true);
    }

}
```

**class GestoreFTP**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GestoreFTP implements Runnable{
    private final String DIRECTORY="C:\\ciao";
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner input;
    PrintWriter output = null;
    private int opzione;

    public GestoreFTP(Socket socket){
        this.socket=socket;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        opzione=input.nextInt();
    }

    public void run(){
        if (opzione==1){
            try {
                System.out.println("Richiesto trasferimento file da: "+socket);

                // intercetto lo stream di input
                ObjectInputStream inputS= new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                // eseguo un cast in file
                File inputFile = (File) inputS.readObject(); 
                // estraggo il nome del file ricevuto
                // e predispongo un file di output
                File outputFile = new File(DIRECTORY+"\\"+inputFile.getName());
                // eseguo il salvataggio sul Server
                salvaFile(inputFile, outputFile);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        else {
            try{
                File fileDir = new File(DIRECTORY);
                String[] fileList = fileDir.list();
                for (int i=0;i<fileList.length;i++)
                    output.println(fileList[i]+"\n");
                String fileDaInviare=input.nextLine();
                File file=new File(fileDaInviare);
                inviaFile(file);
            } catch (Exception e){}
        }
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e){}
    }

    private void salvaFile(File in, File out) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Ricezione file "+in.getName()+" in corso...");
        System.out.println("Dimensione file "+in.getName()+": "+in.length()+" byte");
        // Apertura stream di input sul file inviato
        FileInputStream inS = new FileInputStream(in);
        // Apertura stream di output per salvare il nuovo file
        FileOutputStream outS = new FileOutputStream(out);
        // buffer per contenere una riga del file
        byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
        // leggo una riga per volta e scrivo nel file destinazione
        int i;
        while((i=inS.read(buffer))!=-1){
            outS.write(buffer);
        }
        // chiudo gli stream
        inS.close();
        outS.close();
        System.out.println("...Trasferimento completato!");
    }

    private void inviaFile(File file) throws IOException{
        ObjectOutputStream outS= new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outS.reset();
        outS.writeObject(file);
        outS.flush();
        outS.close();
    }

}
```

**class ClientFTP**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientFTP {
    private final String SERVER="127.0.0.1";
    private final String DIRECTORY="C:\\lavoro\\lodi";
    private final int PORTA=2000;
    private static int opzione;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path="";
        ClientFTP client= new ClientFTP();
        Scanner scelta=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("Scegli un'opzione:");
            System.out.println("1)invia file;");
            System.out.println("2)ricevi file");
            opzione=scelta.nextInt();   
        }while (opzione!=1&&opzione!=2);
        //menu
        //invia
        if (opzione==1){
            try {
                File file;
                // immissione percorso e nome file
                System.out.println("Inserire il path completo (Es.: C:/prova/prova.txt): ");
                Scanner tastiera = new Scanner(System.in);
                try {
                    path=tastiera.nextLine();
                    tastiera.close();
                } catch (InputMismatchException e){
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
                file=new File(path);
                client.inviaFile(file);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //ricevi
        else if (opzione==2){
            try {
                client.riceviFile();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }// main

    private void inviaFile(File file) throws IOException{
        Socket socket=null;
        PrintWriter output=null;
        try {
            socket=new Socket(SERVER, PORTA);
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        } catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output.println(1);
        ObjectOutputStream outS= new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outS.reset();
        outS.writeObject(file);
        outS.flush();
        outS.close();
    }

    private void riceviFile() throws IOException{
        Socket socket=null;
        PrintWriter output=null;
        Scanner input=null;
        Scanner fileDaScegliere=null;
        try {
            socket=new Socket(SERVER, PORTA);
            input = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        } catch(UnknownHostException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output.println(2);
        //stampa il contenuto della cartella nel server
        stampa(input);
        //scelgo il file da prendere
        System.out.println("Inserire il path completo (Es.: C:/prova/prova.txt): ");
        fileDaScegliere = new Scanner(System.in);
        String path=null;
        try {
            path=fileDaScegliere.nextLine();
            fileDaScegliere.close();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        //invio il percorso
        output.println(path);
        // intercetto lo stream di input
        try{
            ObjectInputStream inputS= new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            // eseguo un cast in file
            File inputFile = (File) inputS.readObject(); 
            // estraggo il nome del file ricevuto
            // e predispongo un file di output
            File outputFile = new File(DIRECTORY+"\\"+inputFile.getName());
            // eseguo il salvataggio sul Server
            salvaFile(inputFile, outputFile);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private void stampa(Scanner input){
        Scanner ricezione=null;
        ricezione=input;
        String risposta;
        while(input.hasNextLine()){
            try {
                risposta = input.nextLine(); // passo 3
                System.out.println(risposta);
            }catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }

    private void salvaFile(File in, File out) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Ricezione file "+in.getName()+" in corso...");
        System.out.println("Dimensione file "+in.getName()+": "+in.length()+" byte");
        // Apertura stream di input sul file inviato
        FileInputStream inS = new FileInputStream(in);
        // Apertura stream di output per salvare il nuovo file
        FileOutputStream outS = new FileOutputStream(out);
        // buffer per contenere una riga del file
        byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
        // leggo una riga per volta e scrivo nel file destinazione
        int i;
        while((i=inS.read(buffer))!=-1){
            outS.write(buffer);
        }
        // chiudo gli stream
        inS.close();
        outS.close();
        System.out.println("...Trasferimento completato!");
    }
} // class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your FTPServer does not work like expected. In the `GestoreFTP` you close the socket `socket.close();` instantly after having accept the connection.

So you have an exception when you try to get the inputstream of this closed socket.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't mix readers and writers and object streams on the same socket.
2. Sending a `File` via serialization sends the name, not the content. You have to open the file, and read and write its content to them socket.
3. Serialization is not FTP.

You need to get rid of all this and use input & output steams for everything. Either implement the actual FTP protocol or devise your own. But not this way.